# Yii2 -windows 10 xampp path error

Tags: php, xampp, yii2, windows-10

here i have a Crypt.php file . its a class have two function, and stored it in "\backend\components" folder. i call this file(class) in my controller using this code

```
$security = new \backend\components\Crypt();
```

at run time i am getting this error:

> "Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException
>   Unable to find 'backend\components\Crypt' in file: E:\xampp\htdocs\pope-Admin/backend/components/Crypt.php. Namespace missing?"
>   in this path half of them have slash(/) and half of the part have back slash() how to solve it?

Comment: This error usually means, as it says, that you haven't declared a namespace in your crypt.php file.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Crypt` class file, include namespace declaration like so:

```
<?php

    namespace backend\components;

    class Crypt {
        ...
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `include`(_once) or `require`(_once) keywords to include the Crypt.php file, then just use `new Crypt()`. You cant define an instance of a class like that, you have to include the filw containg the class code and only then you can use the new keyword.